# How can I move an UEFI Win10 install to a BIOS only PC?

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, disk-cloning

We have a ready to use on production environment PC, and want to clone its hard drive on ten workstations.

The problem is the machine is a modern PC with a Windows 10 UEFI setup.

Is there any procedure and any tool which will convert that to a classic BIOS install so all PCs will be able to accept that setup HDD?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you convert your GPT partitions to MBR partitions this should be possible.

Comment: That's all? I feel like there is more to do.

Comment: There is more to do but that's your biggest obstacle if you can't figure out how to do that then it doesn't matter what the rest is

Comment: You'd need to convert GPT to MBR (which can be done with my [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`) software](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)), install a BIOS-mode boot loader for Windows, and deal with whatever hardware differences there are (which would probably involve a lot of rebooting and Windows repairing). There may also be licensing issues (both legal non-technical stuff and Windows complaining when it notices it's running on another computer). It's probably easier to re-install and copy your personal data over.

Comment: @all edited the title since it seems it will be possible. Let's focus on having a good post so it will be useful for future users.

Comment: @RodSmith don't worry about hardware changes adaptation and licensing issues, I've done this a lot of times and it's easier than you think - but until now I always did it from BIOS PC to BIOS PC. Current Windows versions handle hardware changes very stably.

Comment: @RodSmith what can you suggest or write about the second part - the BIOS mode bootloader installing over the UEFI bootloader? I think that if you share something about that, your comment is ready to be posted as answer.

Comment: There may be a Web site that describes how to do it, but if so I don't have a URL handy. The closest I've got is [this blog post,](http://sdnalloh.com/converting-win7-from-mbr-to-gpt/) which describes the opposite type of conversion -- MBR/BIOS to GPT/EFI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to do a partition/filesystem cloning (instead of a full-disk cloning). In that way you can simply clone the system partition (`C:`) on the GPT disk to a partition of a freshly MBR-"initialized" disk.

Note: run `mountvol /R` on the source (GPT) Windows with the PARTITIONED target drive DISCONNECTED before cloning, otherwise you will get a black screen after the Windows boot splash when you boot the cloned Windows.

`ntfsclone` of ntfs-3g in Linux is an example utility to do that. You probably need to shrink the source partition first (can be done "online" with `Disk Management` in Windows) so that is no bigger than the target partition (or extend the cloned NTFS to make it fully utilize the underlying partition with `ntfsresize` included in the same package).

Then install the "BIOS version" of Windows Boot Manager and build the BCD Store to either the same or a separate partition (depends on whether you do Windows multi-boot or BitLocker I guess) with the Windows-builtin `bcdboot`, mark the target partition as `active` with `diskpart`, and fix the MBR and boot sector of the partition with `bootsect` (this is probably not even necessary).

Then you can do full-disk cloning with whichever solution you prefer to produce the remaining clones required.

P.S. Just tested this in Hyper-V and it worked.

Comment: Ok, I was waiting to do it next week and mark as answer if worked, but I'll mark it now since you say it's tested. Thank you for great documentation for community!